# Doesn't let me type an input even tho i did >> cin

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
double c;
int axis, ar;
string answer, lamb;




/*Aspect ratio calculation form*/
/*Y axis is divided by disired aspect ratio, cinema wise the default aspect ratio is 2.35, so       It's divided by that number and we'll get our x RESO*/
/*fntMentaL*/
void aspectRatio()
{
cout << "Enter your Y Axis" << endl;
cin >> axis;
cout << "Enter your desired aspect ratio, if you want a list of known aspect ratios, type Y" <<   endl;
if (answer == "y" || answer == "Y")
{
    cout << "2.39 / A current widescreen cinema standard" << endl;
    cout << "1.77 / HD video std.; U.S. digital broadcast TV std." << endl;
    cout << "1.6667 / The golden ratio" << endl;
    cout << "Now enter your aspect ratio: " << endl;
    cin >> ar;
    c = axis / ar;
    cout << "Your X resolution should be : " << c << endl;
    cout << "Do you want me to set a game command to set this resolution ? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> lamb;
    if (lamb == "y" || lamb == "Y")
    {

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Resolution.txt");
        myfile << c;
        myfile.close();

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It didin't work" << endl;

    }




}
else
{
    cin >> ar;
    c = axis / ar;
    cout << "Your X resolution should be : " << c << endl;
    cout << "Do you want me to set a game command to set this resolution ? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> lamb;
    if (lamb == "y" || lamb == "Y")
    {

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Resolution.txt");
        myfile << c;
        myfile.close();

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It didin't work" << endl;

    }
}


}
```

So yes, I'm having no problems running it but at the last question do you want me to set this resolution and when the guy needs to answer Y or N it doesn't even let me to answer, any thoughts ? The program needs to copy and paste the X resolution that the person inputed but it can't when i can't even start the operation.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should tag it as such :)

Comment: @BrMcMullin: The homework tag was abolished long ago.

Comment: I'll flip the [failbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate#The_failbit) on this one.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh good to know! I retract my earlier statement :)

Comment: You should read [this excellent blog post by Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) about debugging small programs such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to cin >> answer, so when you check if answer is equal to y you get undefined behavior (since answer was never set).

Also, your else block for populating `ar` is a bit awkward - if a user enters something other than `y` it essentially prompts the user for new input. It does not, however, pipe the previous input into `ar`. If that's your intention, it should look more like this, keeping in mind you really should be doing some kind of type checking on the input:

```
/*Aspect ratio calculation form*/
/*Y axis is divided by disired aspect ratio, cinema wise the default aspect ratio is 2.35, so       It's divided by that number and we'll get our x RESO*/
/*fntMentaL*/
void aspectRatio()
{
cout << "Enter your Y Axis" << endl;
cin >> axis;
cout << "Enter your desired aspect ratio, if you want a list of known aspect ratios, type Y" <<   endl;
cin >> answer; //set answer to something!
if (answer == "y" || answer == "Y")
{
    cout << "2.39 / A current widescreen cinema standard" << endl;
    cout << "1.77 / HD video std.; U.S. digital broadcast TV std." << endl;
    cout << "1.6667 / The golden ratio" << endl;
    cout << "Now enter your aspect ratio: " << endl;
    cin >> ar;
    c = axis / ar;
    cout << "Your X resolution should be : " << c << endl;
    cout << "Do you want me to set a game command to set this resolution ? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> lamb;
    if (lamb == "y" || lamb == "Y")
    {

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Resolution.txt");
        myfile << c;
        myfile.close();

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It didin't work" << endl;

    }




}
else
{
    // this is dangerous, you have no idea what 'answer' is, but I gather this is homework,
    // where 'garden path only' type design is OK...
    c = axis / answer; 
    cout << "Your X resolution should be : " << c << endl;
    cout << "Do you want me to set a game command to set this resolution ? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> lamb;
    if (lamb == "y" || lamb == "Y")
    {

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("Resolution.txt");
        myfile << c;
        myfile.close();

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It didin't work" << endl;

    }
}


}
```

Comment: No, i did cin >> lamb;

Comment: Yes, but only AFTER you check if 'answer' == y, which it couldn't be since you never pipe input into answer, so it would never get into the portion of the code that looks to assign lamb.